# Is there a way to safely change the order of devices?

Tags: fdisk

i used to extend contiguous device space,But today i can't extend my /root space
Here is the `fdisk-l`'s output command :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D5A5FA05-3A8D-465C-9D2E-E84AE6A56895

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1050623    1048576   512M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2     1050624 1438072831 1437022208 685.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  1438072832 1439156223    1083392   529M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda4  1439156224 1439361023     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda5  1439361024 1801066495  361705472 172.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  1857503232 1857535999      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda7  1857536000 1897535487   39999488  19.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda8  1897535488 1949536255   52000768  24.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9  1949536256 1953523711    3987456   1.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda10 1801066496 1857503231   56436736  26.9G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

How can i 'change' the order of the `/dev/sda5` and make it just after the my root partition `/dev/sda8` (Just before the swap partition) so i can resize it after formatting the `/dev/sda5` (being a free space) .
Is that possible ? Or if there is another way ?
since , fdisk command shows that : `Partition table entries are not in disk order.`
Here is a screen-shoot [image]

Help please ,Thanks in advance !

Comment: my only advice: before trying anything, do a full backup

Comment: Yeah sure ! thanks